# My SQLI UPDATE ERROR SYNTAX

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update

I have tried to get this to work but i cant

```
$sql="UPDATE QuickLink SET `Order`=$_O, `Text`=$_T, `Address`=$_A WHERE ID=$ID";
```

insert delete and select are all working but i cant get this to work I keep getting the same message.

Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Dojo for Students, `Address`='http://student.classdojo.com/#!/login' WHERE `ID`=' at line 1

Comment: Do an `echo sql;` and you'll likely see the problem: you're going to surround the data with quotes.

Comment: Use parametrized queries with PDO, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql="UPDATE QuickLink SET `Order`='" . $_O . "', `Text`='" . $_T ."', `Address`='" . $_A . "' WHERE ID=$ID";
```

Answer (score 0):

Better use the query with parameters to protect from SQL injection:

```
$sql="UPDATE QuickLink SET `Order`=?, `Text`=?, `Address`=? WHERE ID=?";

if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)) {
    $stmt->bind_param("issi", $_O, $_T, $_A, $ID);
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

If the Order is a string field, put `s` instead of i.

Answer (score 0):

This most likely seems like $_O or $_T has a single quote as Pekka suggested. Also since you are using MYSQLI you should use [mysqli_real_escape_string](https://www.php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string)

Print your $sql before executing like Pekka suggested.

If I had to guess a solution then it would be surrounding text fields with single quotes.

```
$sql="UPDATE QuickLink SET `Order`="'".$_O."'", `Text`="'".$_T."'", `Address`="'".$_A."'" WHERE ID=$ID";
```

Good luck!

Comment: “Also since you are using MYSQLI you should use mysql_real_escape_string” – extra `I` in there?

Comment: Yes, you're showing and linking to `mysql_real_escape_string` instead of `mysqli_real_escape_string` @Kalagen

Comment: If they’re using MySQLi, they should be using parametrized queries – not escaping manually.

Comment: True and that's the better way to do it.